# More than one way to prevent injection

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I have seen mysql_real_escape_string and strip slashes being used in preventing MySQL injections. Or would I need more and place this all into  function, then use the function to prevent injection?

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `fname` REGEXP '%s' AND `lname` REGEXP '%s' LIMIT  
%d", 
mysql_real_escape_string($fname), 
mysql_real_escape_string($lname),
(int)$RowsLimit);
```

Or would it be better to do something like this?
    mysql_real_escape_string(stripslahses($fname)),

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php, among many others

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using mysql_ functions as they are being deprecated. Look into mysqli_ or PDO. Both of which are *prepared statements* and are both faster and more secure when used effectively.

Also, prepared statements do not need to be escaped. **This is explained in a previous answer:**

[Why is using a mysql prepared statement more secure than using the common escape functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732561/why-is-using-a-mysql-prepared-statement-more-secure-than-using-the-common-escape)

[PHP.net on preparing a mysqli_ statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know mysql_functions are being deprecated. I thought I would need to apply several strings to help prevent injection. I will look more into PDO (never head of this before far-less what it stands for).  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a prepared query solution instead of string formatting.

[Are Paramerterized queries necessary in pdo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881156/are-parameterized-queries-in-pdo-necessary-for-request-variables)

[prepared queries with pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299182/prepared-parameterized-query-with-pdo)

[Preventing sql injection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can find more information about prepared queries with PDO.